# What is the best way to remove large amount of data from large tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two large SQL 2008 tables:

- `table_header` with 7 columns and ~ 2 million records
- `table_detail` with 22 columns and ~ 78 million records

The common field between the two is called `item_name` which is `varchar(32)`.

I need to remove all records from `table_detail` where `item_name` is not in `table_header`.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

This is a busy production server. There is no maintenance scheduled anytime soon, but this data needs to be gone now. I can't just run something like:

```
delete from table_detail
where item_name not in (
select item_name from table_header);
```

Comment: Hi Mine, you might want to just pick one format style and stick with it. We will probably help you with certain cleanup on style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced such problems a few times so I have 2 tips for you.

1 Use this script that breaks your delete in packages so you will not run the risk of crashing the log

```
declare @var int, @ var2 int
set @var = (select count (1) from <Table_to_Delete> WHERE <Your-delete-clause>)
set @ var2 = 0

while @ var2 <> @var
begin
set rowcount 50000 - batchsize

print getdate ()
delete from <Table_to_Delete> WHERE <Your-delete-clause>

set @ var2 = @ var2 + @@ ROWCOUNT
print getdate ()

checkpoint - it's optional to avoid log grow

end
```

2) Now if the amount of rows that should remain in the table is really small, example if you are to delete 80 ~ 90% of the table I recommend you copy the table structure and copy the data to the new table. This option is valid if the table structure is simple because you will have to remember to copy all indices, foreing keys, and explicit permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Paging,

```
DECLARE @TopSize INT = 10000
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 10000
DECLARE @MaxLimit INT = 1
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 0

BEGIN TRY
    WHILE (@TopSize <= @MaxLimit)
    BEGIN


    delete TOP ((@TopSize) from table_detail
    where  exists
    (select 1 from table_header 
    where item_name=table_detail.item_name)


        SET @RowCount = @@RowCount

        --PRINT @TopSize
        IF (
                @RowCount = 0
                OR @RowCount IS NULL
                )
            BREAK;
        ELSE
            SET @TopSize = @TopSize + @BatchSize
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    --catch error
END CATCH
```